# getting paper object when raphael is created with callback function

Tags: raphael

Hi I am a beginner with raphael and have question.
Whenever I create a raphael object with a callback function (like below), the paper object isn't returned by the call.

```
var w = 1000;
var h = 400;
var paper = Raphael('svgContainer', w, h, function(){
    console.log('callback');
});
paper.setViewBox(0,0,w,h,true);
```

Why isn't paper the raphael object returned when a callback function is used?

https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Raphael

Whenever i use a callback function paper.setViewBox fails because paper is some kind of On() event function of eve.

It works without the callback.

```
var paper = Raphael('svgContainer', w, h);
```

here is the fiddle about this problem:
[jsfiddle.net/svb0y2un/](http://jsfiddle.net/svb0y2un/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about your none working code of your intent, as you are alerting outside of the callback, so paper may not be defined (as the callback may be called after that).

I 'think' what you need is to understand that the callback function is passed the paper element as the 'context' for the function. This means it will be passed into the 'this' variable inside the callback. So for example this should work....

```
var paper = Raphael('svgContainer', w, h, function(){
    console.log('callback');
    alert('working typeof of paper: '+typeof(this));
    this.setViewBox(0,0,w,h,true);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujzx1w45/)

Comment: my problem is that `paper` isn't the Raphael object any more when a callback function is used. 
I knew that inside the callback `this` is Raphael the object.

the documentation doesn't say that the return is different when a callback function is used it only says `object`is returned. so there is no way to get the raphael object when a callback function is used?

Comment: I think it depends if you are just wanting it to return the paper (not possible afaik), or want the end goal of being able to use the paper (possible). Eg http://jsfiddle.net/8wqsz4pc/1/

Comment: Maybe I was confused about the documentation looks like to always `Returns:
object Paper` even when callback or onReadyCallback functions are used.
Which isn't the case :) 
So thanks for your fiddle.